# filter data between 2 dates in crystal report vb.net

Tags: crystal-reports

I need some help for creating Crystal Reports in VB 2005.

I want to filter data between two dates (like from date and to date) with datetimepicker.
I'm using SQL Server 2000 for the connection.

#### Update:

Thanks for the link, but I'm trying using record selection formula....

Here's my code:

```
Try
        Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
        With cryRpt
            .FileName = ("C:\Documents and Settings\Ratna Ayu\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\Denda\Denda\CrystalReport1.rpt")
            .RecordSelectionFormula = "{pinjam.tglkembali}>='" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "' and {pinjam.tglkembali} =<'" & DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "'"

        End With
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("tdk ada data", , "")
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link

[How to Load and Display Crystal Reports in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/CrystalReports_in_VBNET.aspx)

> The following code shows how to load
>   Crystal Reports in VB.NET, solving all
>   the issues of logon, including sub
>   reports and parameter passing. You can
>   view your reports by simply calling
>   the required functions with its
>   parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub ConfigureCrystalReportsPhotoAlbum2012ByDateNew()
        On Error Resume Next
        sReport = New ReportDocument()
        Dim reportPath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\" & "PhotoAlbum2012.rpt"
        sReport.Load(reportPath)
        Dim selectionFormula As String = "{MemberDetails.Birthdate} >= #" _
            & CDate(frmCustomReport.txtFrom.Text) _
            & "# and {MemberDetails.Birthdate}" _
            & "<=" _
            & "#" _
            & CDate(frmCustomReport.txtTo.Text) _
            & "#"
        Dim myConnectionInfo As ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo()
        'myConnectionInfo.ServerName = "192.168.0.2\SQLExpress" 'Network
        myConnectionInfo.ServerName = ".\SQLExpress"   'Local
        myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "Photo Album 2012"

        myConnectionInfo.UserID = "limitedPermissionAccount"
        myConnectionInfo.Password = ""

        myConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = True
        SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo, sReport)
        frmMain.CrystalReportViewerMain.SelectionFormula = selectionFormula 

        frmMain.CrystalReportViewerMain.ReportSource = sReport
        frmMain.CrystalReportViewerMain.Zoom(100)
        frmMain.CrystalReportViewerMain.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
    End Sub
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's going to far just use this code its very easy.
I built a sample contact application and a report for it and used the code below to filter contacts according to start and end date. `DateTimePicker1` is start and `DateTimePicker2` is end.

```
Private Sub filter_dates()
    Dim objcr As New CrystalReport1
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from Contacts where CDate>='" & CDate(DateTimePicker1.Text) & "' and CDate<='" & CDate(DateTimePicker2.Text) & "' ", conn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    objcr.SetDataSource(dt)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objcr
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim startDate As Date = New Date(2023, 3, 1)
Dim endDate As Date = New Date(2023, 3, 31)

Dim report As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument()
report.Load("C:\Reports\MyReport.rpt")

report.RecordSelectionFormula = "{Orders.OrderDate} >= #" & startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "# AND {Orders.OrderDate} <= #" & endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "#"
```

' Bind data to the report and display it
' ...